# Handle key presses using draw2d and swt

Tags: java, user-interface, focus, swt, draw2d

Every *org.eclipse.draw2d.Figure*  class has *addKeyListener()* method. But when key presses not every Figure handle it. What kind of figure handles key-events?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hm. I don't know real answer. But as variant - add listener to Shell and handle it in some specific way.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is "whichever Figure currently has focus." - otherwise every time you pressed a key, all of your figures would receive the `KeyEvent` and have to handle it. I'd suggest that's unlikely to be what you want.